# AVX512 double precision absolute values of __m512d?

Tags: intel, avx512

I'm looking for an instrinsic to get abs values of __m512d elements. Apparently, `_mm512_andnot_pd` is not available on CORE-AVX512. Is there any equivalent?

Comment: See: [`_mm512_abs_pd`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm512_abs_pd&expand=36), which is available in AVX-512F.

Comment: Abs or andnot... andnot for si512 should be available and give the same result

Comment: The standard method is to AND out the sign bit, i.e. AND with the bit value 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.